# Manually Adjust Bevel Values

Tags: bevel

I'm new to Blender and want to be able to precisely adjust bevel values for faces, edges, and vertices by entering numeric values. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you talking about the bevel modifier or the bevel tool in edit mode?

Comment: @David The bevel tool: "[I] want to be able to precisely adjust bevel values for faces, edges, and vertices..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hit ctrl-B to bevel, and then you can set a number value for however much you want it to bevel.  You probably would want to keep it under 1 to avoid the mesh overlapping itself, but it depends on the mesh.

Comment: hope that was what you wanted, and not what you already know.  Where you talking about bevels that already existed?

Comment: This helped me figure it out! I just had to use ctrl+b and then click out of the auto-adjustment. Then I used the menu in the lower left corner.

Comment: You don't have to click out of the auto-adjustment.  after hitting ctrl-B, you can type in the value and hit enter.  That will give you the same result as typing in the value in the bevel menu.

Comment: If I misunderstood what you meant by auto-adjustment, feel free to correct me.